# JSON schema using javaType from a separate module in the project

Tags: json, module, jsonschema, jsonschema2pojo

How do you use a type that is declared in a separate module of the same project?

I have the following JSON schema:

```
"firstname" : {
  "type" : "object",
  "javaType" : "location.of.class.Name"
}
```

Where the type is declared in a class in my rs module:

```
package location.of.class;

import...

public class Name {
   //some logic
}
```

I want the jsonschema2pojo to generate a class that use the type Name, however I get a separate class generated called Name with exactly the same package name as my existing class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was as simple as adding the relevant dependency to the module in my pom file. For example the below dependency points to an external library *javax.ws.rs* in the same way.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.0-m10</version>
    </dependency>
```

For some reason the jsonschema2pojo plugin doesn't look at the entire project but only refers to the module where you have the plugin.